# Attaching pointers when removing duplicates from a doubly linked list

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I am implementing a function which removes duplicates from an unsorted doubly linked list. I removed other functions to keep the code short and more clear. Please assume other functions like InsertFront do work correctly.

I am having trouble attaching the prev pointer from my Node class when I remove a duplicate. I'm not sure if I am attaching the prev pointer correctly. I am currently getting a seg fault. Thank you.

Here is my header file. dlinkedlist.h

```
#ifndef _DLINKEDLIST_H_
#define _DLINKEDLIST_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <string>
#include <iostream> 

using namespace std;

template <class T>
class Node
{
public:
    T data;
    //string data;
    Node<T>* prev;
    Node<T>* next;

    // default constructor
    Node(T value)
    {
        data = value;
        prev = NULL;
        next = NULL;
    }
};

// DLinkedList class definition
template <class T>
class DLinkedList
{
private:
    // DLinkedList private members
    int size; // number of items stored in list
    Node<T>* front; // references to the front
    Node<T>* back;  //  and back of the list


DLinkedList();
DLinkedList(const DLinkedList& ll);
~DLinkedList();

    void RemoveDuplicates();
}
```

Here is my implementation dlinkedlist.cpp

```
#ifdef _DLINKEDLIST_H_

#include <cstdlib>
#include <stdexcept>
#include "dlinkedlist.h"
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


template <class T>
void DLinkedList<T>::RemoveDuplicates() { 
    Node<T> *current, *runner, *dup;
    current = front;

    cout << "Removing the duplicates..." << endl;

    while (current != NULL && current->next != NULL) {

        runner = current;

        while (runner->next != NULL) {
            if(current->data == runner->next->data) {
                dup = runner->next;
                runner->next = runner->next->next;
                runner->next->prev = runner->next->prev->prev; //trying to connect to previous node. Works without this line.
                delete dup;
            }
            else {
                runner = runner->next;
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }

}
```

Here is my test file. test.cpp

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include "ccqueue.h"
#include "dlinkedlist.h"
#include "ticket.h"

using namespace std;

void LLTest();

int main()
{
  cout << "\nEntering DLinkedList test function..." << endl;
  LLTest();
  cout << "...DLinkedList test function complete!\n" << endl;
  return 0;
}

void LLTest()
{
  // default constructor, InsertFront, InsertBack, ElementAt
  DLinkedList<int> lla;
  lla.InsertFront(2);
  cout << "-------------------------------------------------\n";
  lla.InsertBack(5);
  lla.InsertBack(10);
  lla.InsertBack(2);
  cout << "-------------------------------------------------\n";
  lla.RemoveDuplicates();
}
```

Thank you for your time.

Comment: I'm not sure why this would be causing an issue, but it's probably worth taking a second to see if changing 

`runner->next->prev = runner->next->prev->prev;`
to
`runner->next->prev = runner;`

would make a difference

Comment: Thank you for your response. Unfortunately that did not work and resulted in a seg fault.

Comment: Doubly linked lists are tricky.  It's probably best the define a general-purpose function, like a `removeNode()`, debug it, and then use it as part of your `removeDuplicates()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dup = runner->next;
runner->next = runner->next->next;
runner->next->prev = runner->next->prev->prev;
```

1) After the second line in the code chunk I am pointing out, the `runner->next` becomes NULL when the last element of linked list is the one to be removed. So the next line `runner->next->prev` will crash as it is equivalent to `'NULL->next'`.
So you have to add `if (runner->next != NULL )` between 2nd and 3rd lines. That is you are saying " Connect the next to previous only when next is there ( only when not the last item)

2) Learn debugging tools.

Comment: Thanks for explaining this to me concisely. I will learn how to use debugging tools.

Comment: Yes, I think it solved the problem. I was just testing my linked list by printing it forwards and backwards but found a new problem. When printing the linked list forward with a duplicate at the end, it will remove all duplicates. When printing in reverse with a duplicate at the end, it will remove all duplicates except the last one. If I print in reverse with a unique element at the back, it will print in reverse removing all duplicates.

Comment: I am not clear about what you say, but try adding else part for the if we just added.
`else 
   back = runner;  /* set back to runner, since the back is getting deleted*/`

Comment: Wow! I guess you interpreted what I was trying to describe correctly and changing the back = runner fixed my problem. Thank you so much for your help! Not only did you solve one of my problems, but both . I really appreciate you for helping me out Jay.

Comment: You are welcome. For a note, the answer given by @Sam Varshavchik is perfect and pedagogical.

Answer (score 0):

Let's go through the relevant section of code, very very slowly:

```
 dup = runner->next;
```

This is what you will later `delete`. This is the duplicate node, ok.

```
 runner->next = runner->next->next;
```

It helps, for readability, if you change the above line to "runner->next = dup->next;". It makes it clear that you're relinking `dup`'s predecessor "around it", to point it to the next node after the `dup`.

```
 runner->next->prev = runner->next->prev->prev; //trying to connect to previous node. Works without this line.
```

Ok, `runner->next` is now the node that was originally after `dup`. Now, just stop for a moment, have a cup of coffee, and ask yourself the following question:

In a doubly-linked list, assuming that node `ptr` isn't the last node in the list, what should:

```
ptr->next->prev
```

always be????

Well, `ptr` is a node in the list. `ptr`->next is the next node. What do you expect to find as next node's `prev` value?

If you take a step forward, and then a step back, where do you wind up? Well, in this universe, you will wind up exactly where you started (ignoring effects of relativity). Therefore, in a classical doubly-linked list, `ptr->next->prev` will be `ptr`, assuming that `ptr` is not the last node in the list (pay attention to this part, it will become important).

So, I'm going to make a wild, off the top of my head guess, that what your code should be doing is, instead:

```
 runner->next->prev = runner; // Relink to the previous node
```

But this is not the right answer either. Remember that we made an assumption that `runner` is not the last node in the doubly-linked list. If it is, then `runner->next` would obviously be `NULL`, since `runner`, by definition, is the last node in the list (you deleted the last node in the list, so `runner` is the new last node in the list), so a null pointer dereference will happen here.

So, what do you think should happen here, if `runner` is, indeed, the last node in the list? If you said "nothing", you had the right answer:

```
if (runner->next)
     runner->next->prev = runner;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dup = runner->next;
runner->next = dup->next;
if ( dup->next != NULL )
     dup->next->prev = runner;
else 
     back = runner; /* since we are deleting last element */
delete dup;
```

This may be the a clearer implementation, that replaces :

```
 dup = runner->next;
 runner->next = runner->next->next;
 runner->next->prev = runner->next->prev->prev; //trying to connect to previous node. Works without this line.
 delete dup;
```